# Edges of Vim in Ubuntu terminal are not filled with colorscheme

Tags: ubuntu, vim

As title says, I have problem with not filled edges of vim in terminal.
I use transparent terminal, gruvbox colorscheme in vim and as you can see on image - https://i.stack.imgur.com/dM3ej.jpg, bottom and the edge is not filled.

Can you somehow help me to fix it?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

When a program draws any colors in a terminal window, it can only draw for individual terminal cells.  This is most noticeable when you're drawing backgrounds, but it's true for foregrounds as well.

In your case, your terminal is not an exact number of terminal cells wide.  For example, the width of your terminal could be 128.25 cells.  All the programs in the terminal are going to know is that there's 128 columns, and the extra area is going to be inaccessible to any program using the terminal, and as such, it won't be able to be filled in by Vim or any other terminal program.

You have some choices: you can either live with it, use `gvim` instead, or adjust your terminal emulator (assuming it has that functionality) to eliminate the border.